# how to create the "RoleArn" in amazon s3 service using nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to access the amazon s3 web service through oauth credentials. for that i need to get the temporary security credentials by using AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. for AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity i need to mention "RoleArn" parameter along with oauth access token.

so that RoleArn i can able to create using amazon console management.but how can i create RoleArn using nodejs.

reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the role using javascript, but as it is something you only need to do once, i'd recommend you create it using the IAM management console and get its ARN from there. Also, if you haven't yet, check out the web identity federation playground application: https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: yeha i could create the rolearn once when the user enable the oauth through Login with amazon. so can tell me how can i create through nodejs using oauth access token.